# Is Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) compatible with Windows XP?

Tags: security, anti-virus

Is Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE) compatible with Windows XP?  When I go to the download site, it doesn't mention Windows XP.

Can I use it with Windows XP?

Comment: I was at first unable to download from the Microsoft site, so I went to an alternate site where XP wasn't mentioned. Hence the question.

Thanlks for all your responses.

Comment: out of curiosity, where was the alternative site? Was it part of microsoft?

Comment: Softpedia: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Microsoft-Security-Essentials-Download-131683.html

I got the tip from Download Squad. I checked after midnight early this morning and was informed by the MS site that it was not available. I went to softpedia as the alternate link provided.

Comment: http://www.pcrequirements.net/en/softwares/microsoft-security-essentials-system-requirements/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the site](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/resources.aspx?mkt=en-us&s=1#mainNav):

> **Minimum system requirements for
>   Microsoft Security Essentials**
>
> Operating System: Genuine Windows XP
>   (Service Pack 2 or Service Pack 3);
>   Windows Vista (Gold, Service Pack 1,
>   or Service Pack 2); Windows 7
>
> For Windows XP, a PC with a CPU clock
>   speed of 500 MHz or higher, and 1 GB
>   RAM or higher. For Windows Vista and
>   Windows 7, a PC with a CPU clock speed
>   of 1.0 GHz or higher, and 1 GB RAM or
>   higher. VGA display of 800 × 600 or
>   higher. 140 MB of available hard disk
>   space. An Internet connection is
>   required for installation and to
>   download the latest virus and spyware
>   definitions for Microsoft Security
>   Essentials. Internet Browser: Windows
>   Internet Explorer 6.0 or later.
>   Mozilla Firefox 2.0 or later.
>   Microsoft Security Essentials also
>   supports Windows XP Mode in Windows 7.
>   For more information see the system
>   requirements for Windows XP Mode in
>   Windows 7

Answer (score 7):

[Go here](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/), and click Download.

On the right is a button saying XP 32 Bit.

[image]